# Netbeans javadoc

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

In Netbeans , auto-complete *(ctrl + spacebar)* show **overloaded** methods well.

But when I *ctrl + hover* over the methods , the *javadoc or info* within a popup show only one signature (missing overloaded ones).

So, how to enable it , or any other alternative ?

Comment: This is common with other IDEs as well. The features (especially different ones) will behave differently based on how it's used. When you use auto-complete there's no way for the IDE to know which one you want, so it shows them all to you. However, when it's already written it assumes you're looking for the info for that specific overload. Not a netbeans user but IIRC it's the same for intellij.

Comment: Maybe check if there's a feature to put your cursor after the `.` and auto-comple/replace what you have. That might show them all to you.

Comment: visual studio shows overloaded ones even when the any one of them is used (navigation using up and down arrow keys).

Comment: I was looking for similar feature